# ¿Por que el registro de mi usuario no funciona?

Tags: php, mysql, aplicación-web

estoy practicando diseño web, y tengo problemas al lograr que mi usuario alumno se registre con exito en mi base. Todo funciona bien y tambien las alertas. Pero la consulta falla y no se por que. Mi idea era que el nombre del usuario de mi alumno fuera su numero de control. Habra algun problema con mi formulario o es la consulta?

Esta es mi base de datos y es mi tabla que contiene a los alumnos.

```
CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `alumno_id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alumno_nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `alumno_apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `alumno_numero_control` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `alumno_disciplina` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `alumno_telefono` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `alumno_rol` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pendiente',
  `alumno_usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'chill',
  `alumno_contraseña` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'chill',


);
```

Este es mi formulario, es muy basico.

```
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulario de Registro de Alumnos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Registro de Alumnos</h2>
    <form action="./Modelos/alumno_registro.php" method="POST">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="alumno_nombre" required>
        <br>

        <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="alumno_apellido" required>
        <br>

        <label for="numero_control">Número de Control:</label>
        <input type="text" id="numero_control" name="alumno_numero_control" required>
        <br>

        <label for="disciplina">Disciplina:</label>
        <input type="text" id="disciplina" name="alumno_disciplina" required>
        <br>

        <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
        <input type="text" id="telefono" name="alumno_telefono" required>
        <br>

        <label for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="alumno_contraseña" required>
        <br>

        <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Esta es la logica de mi formulario. Tiene algunas alertas y verificaciones. Yo creo que mi consulta puede estar mal, pero ya revise el formulario las variables y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.

```
<?php
require_once "../Modelos/main.php";

/*== Almacenando datos ==*/
$nombre = limpiar_cadena($_POST['alumno_nombre']);
$apellido = limpiar_cadena($_POST['alumno_apellido']);
$numero_control = limpiar_cadena($_POST['alumno_numero_control']);
$disciplina = limpiar_cadena($_POST['alumno_disciplina']);
$telefono = limpiar_cadena($_POST['alumno_telefono']);
$contraseña = limpiar_cadena($_POST['alumno_contraseña']);

/*== Verificando campos obligatorios ==*/
if ($nombre== "" || $apellido == "" || $numero_control == "" || $disciplina == "" ||
    $telefono == "" || $contraseña == "") {
    $alerta = [
        "Alerta" => "simple",
        "Titulo" => "¡Ocurrió un error inesperado!",
        "Texto" => "No has llenado todos los campos obligatorios.",
        "Icon" => "error"
    ];
    echo json_encode($alerta);
    exit();
}

/*== Verificando integridad de los datos ==*/
if (!preg_match('/^\d{8}$/', $numero_control)) {
    $alerta = [
        "Alerta" => "simple",
        "Titulo" => "¡Ocurrió un error inesperado!",
        "Texto" => "El número de control no coincide con el formato solicitado. Debe tener exactamente 8 caracteres y ser solo números.",
        "Icon" => "error"
    ];
    echo json_encode($alerta);
    exit();
}

if (verificar_datos("[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]{3,20}", $nombre)) {
    $alerta = [
        "Alerta" => "simple",
        "Titulo" => "¡Ocurrió un error inesperado!",
        "Texto" => "El nombre del alumno no coincide con el formato solicitado.",
        "Icon" => "error"
    ];
    echo json_encode($alerta);
    exit();
}

if (verificar_datos("[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]{5,20}", $apellido)) {
    $alerta = [
        "Alerta" => "simple",
        "Titulo" => "Ocurrió un error inesperado",
        "Texto" => "El apellido del alumno no coincide con el formato solicitado.",
        "Icon" => "error"
    ];
    echo json_encode($alerta);
    exit();
}
if (!preg_match('/^\d{7,10}$/', $telefono)) {
    $alerta = [
        "Alerta" => "simple",
        "Titulo" => "¡Ocurrió un error inesperado!",
        "Texto" => "El número de teléfono no coincide con el formato solicitado. Debe tener entre 7 y 10 dígitos y ser solo números.",
        "Icon" => "error"
    ];
    echo json_encode($alerta);
    exit();
}

/*== Guardando datos ==*/
$guardar_alumno = conexion();
$guardar_alumno = $guardar_alumno-> prepare ("INSERT INTO alumnos (alumno_nombre, alumno_apellido, alumno_numero_control, 
alumno_disciplina, alumno_telefono, alumno_usuario, alumno_contraseña)
 VALUES(:nombre, :apellido, :numero_control, :disciplina, :telefono, :usuario, :contraseña)");

$datos = [
    ":nombre" => $nombre,
    ":apellido" => $apellido,
    ":numero_control" => $numero_control,
    ":disciplina" => $disciplina,
    ":telefono" => $telefono,
    ":usuario" =>$numero_control,
    ":contraseña" => $contraseña
];

$guardar_alumno->execute($datos);

if ($guardar_alumno->rowCount() == 1) {
    $alerta = [
        "Alerta" => "limpiar",
        "Titulo" => "¡Alumno registrado!",
        "Texto" => "Los datos del alumno se han registrado.",
        "Icon" => "success"
    ];
} else {
    $alerta = [
        "Alerta" => "simple",
        "Titulo" => "¡Ocurrió un error inesperado!",
        "Texto" => "No hemos podido registrar los datos del alumno.",
        "Icon" => "error"
    ];
}

echo json_encode($alerta);
$guardar_alumno = null;
?>
```

Comment: Hola Wiccs. ¿Que mensaje obtenes al completar el formulario sin errores? Mi pregunta es para saber en algún momento obtenes `"¡Alumno registrado!"`

Answer (score 0):

El error es de logica y se da desde la creacion de la tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `alumno_id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alumno_nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `alumno_apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `alumno_numero_control` int(20) NOT NULL,
```

**alumno_numero_control** es `int` osea es un numero entero, y tu quieres meterle letras, osea el nombre.

Yo que tu, ese control lo dejaba con algun documento del alumno en cuestion o lo pasas a `varchar` y listo.